# Interactive JS Menu with smooth show/hide content and scroll to top with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am having troubles creating a completely smooth show/hide and scroll menu with jQuery
Is there any better solution than this?

[SEE FULL DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2n40cssz/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

    $("#showIndex1").click(function(){
        $("#index1").show(1500);
        $("#index2").hide(1500)
    });
    $("#showIndex2").click(function(){
        $("#index2").show(1500);
        $("#index1").hide(1500)
    });

   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top - 20

    }, 1600, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        });
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100px">

<a href="#indexAchor1" id="showIndex1"><h2 id="indexAchor1">index1</h2></a>
<div id="index1" style="display: none;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<a href="#indexAchor2" id="showIndex2"><h2 id="indexAchor2">index2</h2></a>
<div id="index2" style="display: none;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

</div>
```

[SEE FULL DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2n40cssz/)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: If you see the demo, it does not work.. 
And the action is not smooth but jumps at the end.. 
Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".home").click(function(){
        $("#index1, #index2, #index3").hide();
    });
    $("#showIndex1").click(function(){
        $("#index1").show();
        $("#index2, #index3").hide()
    });
    $("#showIndex2").click(function(){
        $("#index2").show();
        $("#index1, #index3").hide()
    });
    $("#showIndex3").click(function(){
        $("#index3").show();
        $("#index1, #index2").hide()
    });
   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top

    }, 1600, function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        });
});

});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/2n40cssz/51/)

### Update

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/2n40cssz/52/)

Comment: Thank you, but I need the menu to open and close also with a smooth delay of about 1000..

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But i need the hide to be smooth to! opening - closing and scrolling all smooth..